# getUriForFile returning different URIs from different activities

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to change some old app from file:// to content:// URIs and I'm having mixed results.

I found this link in another StackOverflow question: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en and followed the tutorial there.

This is the code I'm using to create the file and get the URI before calling the camera

```
photoFile = null;
try {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "qmobility");
    photoFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
}
if (photoFile != null) {
    String authority = this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".qphoto.GenericFileProvider";
    photoURI = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            authority,
            photoFile);
}
```

I have this provider defined in my manifest

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="device.qmobility.quiter.com.qmobilitydeviceapp.qphoto.GenericFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And the file_paths file contains this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="/Pictures/"/>
</paths>
```

The app is supposed to store the pictures in this path: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/qmobility/` and I'm getting this path from my main activity.

But in other activity I'm getting the following values:
storageDir: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/qmobility`
photoFile: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/qmobility/JPEG_20180308_133202_-1027794396.jpg`
authority: `device.qmobility.quiter.com.qmobilitydeviceapp.qphoto.GenericFileProvider`
photoUri: `content://device.qmobility.quiter.com.qmobilitydeviceapp.qphoto.GenericFileProvider/external_files/qmobility/JPEG_20180308_133255_-1768273985.jpg`

What should I do to get an URI of the form `content:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/qmobility/JPEG_20180308_133255_-1768273985.jpg`????

Comment: I use this in my app and have no problem - I didn't adapt the FileProvider however- does it work any differently if you replace GenericFileProvider with the FileProvider? I also just use my provider path as ```<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>``` and would just build up the uri myself knowing that the image is saved in the public directory. I'm not sure if you're going wrong through something I can't see or you are just complicating it slightly by using your GenericFileProvider. Also, use a constant for your authority, it's hardcoded in your manifest so don't have it dynamic

Comment: `What should I do to get an URI of the form content:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/qmobility/JPEG_20180308_133255_-1768273985.jpg????` That is impossible of course as there is no provider specified.

Comment: As has been said before: Change `GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile()` to `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.

Comment: @greenapps I tried that. I'm getting the same URI pattern that works on some (newer) versions of Android but makes the camera crash on older SDK versions

Comment: On older versions the camera apps do not know how to handle a content scheme maybe. So then provide a file scheme. Do not use a content provider then. Find out which Android versions are involved that you call 'older'.